# Recommended ways to store form data to allow for additional new forms

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

I'm building a site that will consist mainly of large forms for users to fill out. If I want to allow for future forms to be added easily, what's the best way to store the form data?

Storing each value in it's own column is tedious and doesn't allow to easily "drop" in new forms. Is XML a good way to go? Other suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use JSON to save it.But it's difficult to search them.

JSON will use more less disk space,and it's good to read.